# deleting a comment you posted with php code?

Tags: php, sql, database

I was wondering if you can maybe help me out here... I created a link sharing website and managed to create a comment on a shared link.

I want to give you a scenario of what I would like to achieve. Every comment made by user_1 for instance, can only be deleted by user_1 and admin.

I understand that when "deleting" it from the php page it must also be dropped from the database. How can you do this?

```
//I pressume where I INSERTED my post's 'vales' I must DELETE them again from there??
//It is very much alike from reply.php's code where you INSERT the data into the database. Now I just want to delete it.
//I don't know if this code below is correct??

$sql = "DELETE FROM 
            posts(post_content,
                  post_date,
                  post_topic,
                  post_by) 
        WHERE ('" . $_POST['reply-content'] . "',
                NOW(),
                " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . ",
                " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . ")";


$result = mysql_query($sql);

if(!$result)
{
    echo 'Your reply has not been saved, please try again later.';
}
else
{
    echo 'Your comment has been deleted!';
}
```

Comment: Where do you generate the link to delete the comment? Your DELETE-Statement only needs the primary key as condition and the syntax is like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Delete query has major syntax errors. You don't delete individual fields from a table - you CAN'T. you can only delete entire records. The proper syntax is:

```
DELETE FROM sometable WHERE (...)
```

Your where clause also has errors. You're not doing any comparison operations, just listing some values. Again, a syntax error. Most like you'd want this (guessing at your post's table primary key field name):

```
DELETE FROM posts WHERE (post_id = $id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give your comments ID's, and simply perform `delete from posts where ID = $id`.

The SQL statement you currently have won't even execute. Look at the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) for how the syntax works.

Answer (score 0):

What would really be helpful is some separation of presentation logic from db logic from bus. logic. Try a MVC pattern, which makes it a lot easier to parse through the code and to only look at DB or presentation or bus. logic code. Then, we could focus on the answer to the question posted.